# Changing azure webjob occurrence

Tags: azure

I published a Azure webjob and that is working fine, however I want to change the scheduled time to minutes. I can't find the option to change it onto minutes in the portal.

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the schedule via Visual Studio.

1. Open project in Visual Studio.
2. In Solution Explorer, expand project properties, delete Webjob-publish-settings.json and confirm when prompted. (You'll re-create this shortly)
3. Right-click project in Solution Explorer, Publish as Azure WebJob
4. Select "Run on a Schedule" in the "WebJob Run Mode" list.
5. Set recurrence, start date/time and (optionally) end date/time and recurrence pattern.
6. Click OK. (This should re-create .json settings file with new config info)
7. Click Publish in the dialog box to publish the WebJob with the new schedule.

Source: Azure 70-532 Study Guide

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: This option is no longer available as of VS2015 and the latest Azure SDK. You can only choose Continuous or On Demand from the Publish UI.

Answer (score 1):

Azure WebJobs which are published to run on a schedule provision a Scheduler item within the Azure Portal. This can be adjusted to a different schedule in the portal without having to republish your application. In the Manage portal scroll down to Scheduler, click through until you find your WebJob. From there you can edit the frequency, start time, etc.

Keep in mind that if you republish your source for the WebJob this change will be reverted to the original time so you should modify the frequency for the WebJob there too. To do that open the properties folder for your WebJob project. Then open the "webjob-publish-settings.json" file. Change jobRecurrenceFrequency to hour as you see here, "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour".

Hope that helps.

Edit: here is a screen shot.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew about the portal, however that didn't show the minutes.

Comment: It does show the minutes. Here is a screen grab I did that shows it. Hope that helps.

Comment: Very useful tip! Thanks Mark

Comment: I cant see the scheduler options in my portal - what am i missing?